# Fatal error no sistema de login

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo um sistema de login em PHP e resultou em um fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\avulso-2\valida-usuario.php on line 10

```
    <?php
      $conecta = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "avulso");

      $login = $conecta->real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
      $senha = $conecta->real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

      $sql_usuario = "SELECT id, nome, login, senha FROM usuario WHERE login = " .$login. " AND senha = " .$senha. "LIMIT 1";
     $query_usuario = $conecta->query($sql_usuario);

     if($query_usuario->num_rows() != 1){ /* Nesta linha que ocorreu o erro: "Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\avulso-2\valida-usuario.php on line 10" */

    echo "Login inválido ou inexistente!";
     }
     else{
         $rs_usuario = $query_usuario->fetch_assoc();

         if(!isset($_SESSION)){
         session_star();
         $_SESSION['id'] = $rs_usuario['id'];
         $_SESSION['nome'] = $rs_usuario['nome'];

         header("Location: index.php"); exit;
      }

     }
   ?>
```

Comment: Sua consulta falhou, em valores do tipo texto é preciso que eles estejam entre aspas simples. vc pode fazer um teste, de um echo na sua sql e teste no banco e veja o erro retornado.

Comment: $sql_usuario = "SELECT id, nome, login, senha FROM usuario WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";

 ^ Assim, Rray?

Comment: Sim, de um echo em `$sql_usuario` e roda a consulta no banco(pode ser phpmyadmin ou outro) veja qual o erro aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Valores do tipo texto devem estar entre aspas simples na sua consulta, como no código abaixo. [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) é uma propriedade e não um método logo não precisa dos parentesses.

```
$sql_usuario = "SELECT id, nome, login, senha FROM usuario WHERE login = '" .$login. "' AND senha = '" .$senha. "' LIMIT 1";
 $query_usuario = $conecta->query($sql_usuario);

 if($query_usuario->num_rows != 1){
```